# How can I search a document in python to find specific words?

Tags: python

Trying to be able to search in doc, docx, rtf, pdf, excel, ect... But if that's not possible using one program just help me with doc/docx. Thanks!

Comment: Help you in what way?

Comment: -what module I can use to accomplish parsing a doc

Comment: Try a google search for "python read word document".

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for with [Textract](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#)